# Why use Specs2 over JUnit?

Tags: scala, junit, sbt, scalatest, spec2

We went through online material such as scalatest site. What are advantages of using scala testing framework Specs2? How does it add to the project over JUnit?

Comment: For the very first -- you will stop eye bleeding from `thisMethodShouldDoThisAndThan` notation, which is common in JUnit.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a little reluctant to answer this because it's a quite subjective thing.

But I could summarise it as **"In the same way Scala gives you new and cleaner ways to solve problems over Java, Specs2 gives you new and cleaner ways to test over JUnit"**.

Some quick examples:

### Mockito is a first-class citizen

[Mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/) is my favourite JVM mocking library; using it with Specs2 is as simple as [mixing in a trait](https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-3.2/org.specs2.guide.UseMockito.html) and you get a nice DSL for verification:

```
class MySpec extends Specification with Mockito { 
   // Setup:
   val mockConnection = mock[Connection]

   ...

   // Verification: (in a test)
   there was one(mockConnection).get("www.google.com")
}
```

### ScalaCheck is a first-class citizen

[ScalaCheck](http://scalacheck.org/) can save a heap of time "fuzzing" inputs to your functions, and again, [a simple trait mixin](https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-3.2/org.specs2.guide.UseScalaCheck.html) gets you all of its power within your Specs2 tests.

### Run a test in a `Scope`

Ever had a problem where tests would work on your machine but break elsewhere, because your machine ran them in a certain order? Or got into "mocking hell" due to interactions between stubbed collaborator behaviour? Specs2 lets you put the entire test into a Scope to contain all of that state and stop it from leaking into other tests:

```
class AnotherSpec extends Specification with Mockito {

  class FooScope extends Scope {
    val mockResponse = mock[Response]
    val mockConnection = mock[Connection]
    ...
    mockConnection.execute returns mockResponse

    def frobulate(s:String) = {
      // Use mockResponse, mockConnection, etc ...
    }
  }

"My thing" should {

  "Do stuff" in new FooScope {
    frobulate("hello")

    there was one(mockConnection).post(...)
  }
}
```

`Scope`s help you DRY up your tests as well as stop state leaks between them.

### Plus

- "Blocks" to group related tests (`"My thing" should`)
- Readable, space-separated test names (`"throw an exception if argument < 0" in`)
- Readable DSL for matching (`result must have length(7)`)
- Matchers for Scala-idiomatic types (`result must beNone`)
- Easily [temporarily disable](https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-3.2/org.specs2.guide.PendingUntilFixedExamples.html) a test with `pending`
- [Generate HTML reports/output](https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-3.2/org.specs2.guide.HtmlOutput.html) with a DSL

### Downsides

In an attempt to make this answer slightly more objective, I should also point out [this article by the esteemed Bill Venners](http://www.artima.com/articles/compile_time.html) about compile time which points out that a Specs2 `mutable.Specification`, due to large numbers of implicits and function declarations, is almost an order-of-magnitude slower to compile than a roughly-equivalent JUnit test. It also does not scale well over large numbers of tests. Or at least it didn't when the article was written in early 2013. There are now [approaches you can use](https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-3.2/org.specs2.guide.LightweightSpecs.html) to address this.

Comment: O gosh. U did a very good jog writing this answer. I did'nt know about this downside, mybe because my application do a few tests.